# How to make the logo in the navbar "clickable"?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

This is how I show my logo in the navbar:

```
<img class="navbar-brand" href="/" src="logo.png" alt="HomePage">
```

The logo image appears as it is expected except that I can't click it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: place it inside an anchor tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try something like

```
<a href="/"><img class="navbar-brand" src="logo.png" alt="HomePage"></a>
```

Comment: Is it possible to increase the size of the logo?

Comment: You can edit the css for navbar-brand class or add it through a style attribute like `style="width:300px"` for example